# Removing a Duplicate in one column using the condition from another using Dplyr

Tags: r, duplicates

```
 mtime          Speed
 04:27:00.000   83,0903472900391
 04:28:00.000   90,4319076538086
 04:28:00.000   83,3221054077148
```

I need to remove the duplicates on the mtime column in R by using the condition of the maximum value for speed.
the resulting table should look like this.

```
 mtime          Speed
 04:27:00.000   83,0903472900391
 04:28:00.000   90,4319076538086
```

There can be more than one duplicate value for time but it should remove all the values except the one with the highest speed.

```
k<- filter(kj, unique(mtime), max(vPkwCommon))
```

when I tried this using dplyr, it returned `"Error: ‘max’ not meaningful for factors"`

Any suggestions?

Comment: as the error said, you have to transform the `mtime` column to character or to a time object. Use for example `as.character(d$mtime)`

Comment: not an answer because you asked for `dplyr`, but `data.table` solution would be `setDT(kj); kj[, max(as.character(as.numeric(Speed))), by = mtime]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order first your rows and then filter out duplicates in the `mtime` columns:

```
kj %>% arrange (mtime, - Speed) %>% filter (!duplicated (mtime))
```

The `-` sign will order decreasingly your Speed column. Then, when you use the `!duplicated` filter, just the first value in the duplicated run of `mtime` will be kept, and this will include the maximum value of `Speed`.